# Dictionary Print Out All Word Of What I Type In

Tags: python, project

I need to create a program which prints out all the word in the dictionary that I wrote, So let's say I write house, It could come out like

> home, house, high, hollow, out, over, overrated, on, united, untitled, urgent, song, silent, silence, sorry, emotion, elf, egg, end

So it gets all the word out of my dictionary with the word I wrote in, here is the code.

```
#User types in a word
word = input("Type in a word: ")

#initiate the dictionary struct.
dictionary = {}
#run through the dictionary file, one line at a time.
with open("dict.txt") as dict_filehandle:
for cword in dict_filehandle:
#here a single line has been placed into the variable cword.

    #no newlines are allowed in the words.
    cword=cword.replace("\n","");

    #give the given word the value 1.
    dictionary[cword]=1;

#here we have a dictionary struct.

#here we push through all the words in the dictionary


print(dictionary["house"])
```

In the code I have above, I made it search "house" and it shows that it's true by getting the number 1, I don't know how to do the thing I said above but I need to be able to do it since it's a school project and my teacher recommended for us to look on the internet so I decided to just ask people.

Comment: Your indention is off. And could you please show what is in the `dict.txt` file?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry https://www.dropbox.com/s/4a1ps1hkl187f8m/dict.txt?dl=0

Comment: I do not understand your issue, you want the user to type in `home` and your program would recognize that refers to `house` in your dictionary?  the variable `word` is not used in your code what so ever so I don't see how that connection would be made...

Comment: "all the word out of my dictionary"? `print(" ".join(list(dictionary.keys())))` ?

Comment: @Kobbi I was about to ask you to put your text file in your question, until I saw its size.....

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen If I understand him correctly, he wants to print all the synonyms of the word that is typed in. But your right, he never uses `word` in his code, so I don't see how he is using the user input.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. `dict.txt` is just a gigantic list of words, one word per line. How would you expect entering "house" in `word` would only return certain words from that list?

Comment: @roganjosh I think he is trying to print all the **synonyms** of the word that is typed in. But its hard to understand him correctly as is.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry the issue being though that there is no attempt anywhere to collect words into groups of synonyms :(

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, I really don't think he's ready to do something like that. That would require a lot of complex logic to be able to recognize work synonyms, such  as `home` and `abode`.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry even more complicated when "house" should also return the word "egg"! So the return words only need some vague association with the input

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I'm sorry for my bad explanation, the word "house" was an example, It's supposed to get every single H word in the dictionary then every single O word in the dictionary and so on, I am not able to accomplish this myself and I see I have received alot of negative feedback for this post :/

Comment: Nevermind , My teacher said that this project was way too hard for us so he told us that he is goign to change it, but thanks everyone who tried to help me with this project I really appreciate you doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a crisp solution, but an approach and an explanation that is longer for a comment:

Before you could get all the words that match a particular word someone gives to your program, you need to classify the words in your file into categories and establish mappings. That is, it should be established somewhere, preferably in your data file, to which words an entry can map to. This however, is a bit of a complex task. As you can see, a given word and the other words you want to refer to that word needs to be modeled through some logic. Building this logic is the entirety of your problem. If what you need is to give standard synonyms for a given word, I can suggest something like: [words api](https://www.wordsapi.com/). I am not really aware of how their api works and what the usage limits are. If you do a bit of searching, you might be able to find an open source solution as well. Good luck!